# Simplifying function to check array matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that checks whether a passed arg equals one of the conditions in an array.

For example:

```
function doesMatch(passedData) {
  return (
    passedData === "blue" ||
    passedData === "green" ||
    passedData === "red"
  );
}
```

If the passed value matches any of the data, then it will return true. If it doesn't find a match it returns false and we know it's not a match.

Works fine but seems messy (have more data than this). I was trying to get it working with a `.forEach` and an array with all of the values to test against, but I'm not quite getting it right.

```
function doesMatch(passedData) {
    ["blue", "green", "red"].forEach((colour) => {
        return passedData === colour
    });
}
```

How can I make my latter function have the same result as the former? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you want to use an array then you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: @FelixKling so much easier thanks! If you put this as an answer I will mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `Array.prototype.forEach` does not work is because the `return` value of the callback is ignored -

```js
function doesMatch (passedData)
{ let matched = false;
    ["blue", "green", "red"].forEach((colour) => {
        if (colour === passedData)
          matched = true;
    });
    return matched;
}

console.log(doesMatch("red"));    // true
console.log(doesMatch("cyan"));   // false
```

But we can write this more succinctly using `for..of` loop -

```js
function doesMatch (query)
{ for (const colour of ['blue', 'green', 'red']) 
    if (colour === query)
      return true
  return false
}

console.log(doesMatch("red"))     // true
console.log(doesMatch("cyan"))    // false
```

Or if you want to use arrow expressions, we can utilise `Array.prototype.some` -

```js
const doesMatch = q =>
  ['blue', 'green', 'red'].some(colour => colour === q)

console.log(doesMatch("red"))     // true
console.log(doesMatch("cyan"))    // false
```

Felix's suggestion to use `switch` or `Set`/`Set.prototype.has` is also a great recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple alternatives using various data structures, but I think the most reasonable ones would be to either use a `switch` statement or a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

#### Switch statement

```
function doesMatch(passedData) {
  switch(passedData) {
    case "blue":
    case "green":
    case "red":
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

#### Set

```
const values = new Set(['blue', 'green', 'red']);

function doesMatch(passedData) {
  return values.has(passedData);
}
```